# Compute the Second Order Derivative of Digital Image with Finite Differences

Tags: image-processing, derivative, gradient, finite-differences

I was looking for how to compute second order derivative of an image and came across the question [kernels to Compute Second Order Derivative of Digital Image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10605/kernels-to-compute-second-order-derivative-of-digital-image). In the top voted answer, it gives an example to get $3\times 3$ kernel $I_{xx}$ and $I_{xy}$. The 1st order derivative filter is defined as
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then

> $$
>  I_{xx} = I_x \cdot I_x = \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & 1 \\
>  -1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\cdot\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & 1 \\
>  -1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)=\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & -2 & 1 \\
>  2 & -4 & 2 \\
>  1 & -2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

and

> $$
> I_{xy} = I_y \cdot I_x = \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & -1 \\
>  1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\cdot\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -1 & 1 \\
>  -1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)=\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 0 & -1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  -1 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

The computation of $I_{xx}$ makes sense to me, however, for $I_{xy}$, shouldn't it be defined as below?

$$
I_{xy} = I_x \cdot I_y = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention that convolution mean flipping the kernel both on the `x` and `y` axis.
Hence the first element is a multiplication of $ -1 \cdot -1 $ which yields $ 1 $ as in the answer in the original post.

Pay attention that this is a discrete approximation of the gradient based on Finite Differences. This specific one is based on the Sobel 1st derivative filter.
In [Finite Differences Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) you may find more variations.
As usual, the longer the filter the better the accuracy of the approximation with longer tarnsients.

Comment: Ah! I was only flipping the kernel on the x axis only... Actually there is no difference between (Iy * Ix) and (Ix * Iy). Thanks!

Comment: The longer it is means the longer its transient as well.

Comment: @David, You're correct. I will add that.